# Navigate to UITableViewController by selecting UITableView Cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm Using `UITableView` **without a navigation controller**. My problem is, when I click a particular cell, It doesn't push to another `UIViewController`.

Here is my code,

```
-(void)goToMyView
{
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
TOMenuViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

How do I move to another view controller and come back from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this line of code:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

use this line of code:

```
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When you want to go back to your old view controller in the new view controller use:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

And for animation before you present your view controller use:

```
  vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help,But it's animating from bottom to top. I need it from right side to left.

Comment: @user2745507 You want a different animation?

Comment: @user2745507 And remember if this answer helps give a check.

Answer (score 0):

try to use prepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    //you have to give an id to segue, in storyboard

   if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"detail"]) {

     //passing strings or whatever you want here so:
    [segue.destinationViewController setStringDetail: yourString]; 

 }
```

in detailViewController the back button is automatically created

Answer (score 0):

see my answer here, how to change the modal segue's animation to look like a push segue.

[Pushing a view to a UINavigationController that's not in the same view hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686113/pushing-a-view-to-a-uinavigationcontroller-thats-not-in-the-same-view-hierarchy/18694230#18694230)